# UICollectionView becomeFirstResponder wrong behavior

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, becomefirstresponder

Im using UIColletion view with custom cell with UITextField inside it. As I found out, the collectionView does automatic scrolling, when textField become first responder so the keyboard doesn't cover edited field.

The problem is, that this function isn't working properly. It scrolls the textfield to right place just above the keyboard but next it scrolls a little bit lower, co the keyboard hides part of textfield.

I tried fresh new project with only one simple collection view with just one prototype cell with textfield in it and it's not working either.

In my original project with much more complicated cell the second scroll is much bigger so the whole textfield is under keyboard.

Is that a bug in collection view or Im doing something wrong? (in the simple project there almost cannot be anything wrong....

Comment: Could you add some of the code you're using in your new, small project?

Comment: Posted as new answer

Comment: @MartinKubišta Please check the answer bellow. Added a snippet that seems like a more versatile solution as well

Comment: Having a similar issue. Any updates?

Answer (score 0):

As for my sample project.

UICollectionViewController

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class CollectionCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        return 50
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell

        cell?.field.backgroundColor = .red

        return cell ?? UICollectionViewCell()
    }

}
```

UICollectionViewCell

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var field: UITextField!
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just recreated your project and seems to be working nice for me testing on an iPhone 7 plus.

The collection view scrolls and reveals the textfield. Now one issue is that the padding below the keyboard is not always the same. My suggestion in your case is to make sure you have the constraints for your textfield in place and try again. That might make a difference.

On the other hand, I would suggest to use a ScrollView instead of a collection view. 
Collection views have cell reuse which might cause problems to you in terms of cells been reused and textfields being deallocated.

What I usually do when having a form with lots of TextFields is the following:

- Create a scrollView and pin to all the edges. Especially the bottom constraint is important
- Add view in the scrollView pin it to all the edges and make the width and height of your inclosed UIView equal to the width and height of the ScrollViews superview. (That way the scroll insets will scale correctly)
- Add your textFields as Subviews to the UIView above
- Add observers for keyboard notifications in your UIViewController and animate the bottom constraint of the scrollView to the height of the keyboard and back to 0 when the keyboard moves a way from the screen.

That way you make sure that you control the screen animations and you can add more padding if you feel necessary. The scrollView will handle the resisting and get your textField placed in the correct viewport.

Furthermore, you will be able to have references to all of your textFields. Either by creating outlets or by adding them to an OutletCollection.

I usually do the latter in order to keep them in order and move the focus to the next one on the list.

```
import UIKit

class KeyboardViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var bottomScrollViewConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func hideKeyboard(_ sender: Any) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            self.bottomScrollViewConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height //Add more padding here if you want
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, animations: { 
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }

    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        self.bottomScrollViewConstraint.constant = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I know about this solution, but it cannot be done in our project. The whole screen is a some sort of form, with many different kinds of inputs and textfield is only one of this kind of inputs. And its not static but completely generated by code around our collectionview subclass which handles some layout changes, basic inputs, items reordering and many more...

Comment: Still the collection view autonomous behaviour looks like a bug for me. I tried it with accessory view and its behave the same. https://youtu.be/lN-I59qF2cY